# Calculate maximum of a subrange in a table based on multiple conditions

Tags: excel-formula

I want to calculate the maximum amount of rain fallen on a day.

Column B contains the date as YYYYMMDD  (value, not text)
Column C contains the number of the hour of measurement (ranging from 1 until 24)
Column N contains the amount of rain fallen in [mm] : 0 if no rain; positive integer if rain has fallen

What formula calculates the maximum amount of rain fallen on a day?
[image: rain fallen each hour of january 4th 2000 and the first 5 hours of january 5th 2000]

So:
for january 4th I want to sum N2:N25
for january 5th I want to sum N26:N49
etc.
and return the maximum of those calculated values

REMARK:
a value of -1 in column N indicates 'not measured' and shoudl be treated as 'no rain' (= 0)

Comment: Can you mockup how you would like the return to look?

Comment: I would like to return the total of the rain fallen on the day that the most rain has fallen that year.

Comment: Is it one year per sheet or are they all in the same table?

Comment: II have a separate sheet for every year from 2000 until 2019.
Those sheets have 8761 or 8785 rows (= 365 or 366 days plus a header)

Comment: I'm sorry to keep throwing on comments, but I think I jumped the gun a little. Since the -1 is to be treated as a zero you can use this formula instead:


`=MAX(SUMIFS(N1:N10000,B1:B10000,B1:B10000,N1:N10000,">"&0))`


And for the date value:


`=OFFSET(B2,MATCH(G20,(SUMIFS(N1:N10000,B1:B10000,B1:B10000,N1:N10000,">"&0)),0),0)`


Both are array formulas still. They'll completely ignore negative values.

Comment: I was just trying to adjust the formula for that when I read your comment. 
There is one other thing: it takes long to calculate. Now my worksheet takes MINUTES to calculate (20 years) every time I change something or open the file. Before it just tooks seconds. I suppose it is because of the range to calculate for every test. If that could be limited to just 24 rows it should improve much. Further speed could be gained if the calculation would be performed only every 24th row. But I suppose that's not easy to achieve.

Comment: My formula looks like =MAX(SUMIFS(INDIRECT($D16&"!$N$2:$N$" &$C16+1), INDIRECT($D16&"!$N$2:$N$" &$C16+1),">"&0,INDIRECT($D16&"!$B$2:$B$" &$C16+1), INDIRECT($D16&"!$B$2:$B$" &$C16+1))) 
as $C16 contains the number of days in the year referenced by $D16  (being also the name of the sheet)

Comment: Are helper columns allowed? We can speed this up considerably if you put the following formula in an empty column and dragged it down:

`=IF(B2=1,SUMIF(N2:N25,">"&0),"")`

Then a simple `=MAX(O:O)`, where O:O is our helper column would give you your result.

Finally to find the date `=OFFSET(A2,MATCH(G20,O:O,0),0)` where G20 refers to the cell that the MAX() function is in and O:O is our helper column.

It accomplishes the same thing, just faster and adds a helper column. These are not array formula.

Comment: No i would like to avoid helper columns as in total I already need about 30 columns of results just for rain and I also have other measurements to deal with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one, my testing area only extended 1,000 rows, but it should scale nicely.

`=MAX(SUMIFS(N2:N1000,B2:B1000,B2:B1000))`

Remember to enter as an array formula by confirming with CNTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

Comment: To find what day that value occurred upon, use this formula:

`=OFFSET(B2,MATCH(G20,SUMIFS(N2:N1000,B2:B1000,B24:B1023),0)+23,0)`

G20 refers to the cell containing above formula (max rain on a given day). It will return the date value, not formatted.

Another array formula, so remember CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER.

Comment: I am amazed, but that works - just wondering why you start the second range on the 23rd hour?

Comment: Apparently I can't edit a comment after someone replies to it:

Use this formula to find the date:

`=OFFSET(B2,MATCH(G20,SUMIFS(N2:N1000,B2:B1000,B2:B1000),0),0)`
Enter it as an array formula with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER
It will return an unformatted date code.

Comment: I can only thank you for the amazing solution for finding the maximum AND the date

Comment: This was an amazing, eye-opening solution. Big thumbs-up from me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an ugly solution that takes 3 cells, but is much faster than my first formula:

`=MAX(SUMIF(N2:N25,">"&0),SUMIF(N26:N49,">"&0),SUMIF(N50:N73,">"&0),SUMIF(N74:N97,">"&0),SUMIF(N98:N121,">"&0),SUMIF(N122:N145,">"&0),SUMIF(N146:N169,">"&0),SUMIF(N170:N193,">"&0),SUMIF(N194:N217,">"&0),SUMIF(N218:N241,">"&0),SUMIF(N242:N265,">"&0),SUMIF(N266:N289,">"&0),SUMIF(N290:N313,">"&0),SUMIF(N314:N337,">"&0),SUMIF(N338:N361,">"&0),SUMIF(N362:N385,">"&0),SUMIF(N386:N409,">"&0),SUMIF(N410:N433,">"&0),SUMIF(N434:N457,">"&0),SUMIF(N458:N481,">"&0),SUMIF(N482:N505,">"&0),SUMIF(N506:N529,">"&0),SUMIF(N530:N553,">"&0),SUMIF(N554:N577,">"&0),SUMIF(N578:N601,">"&0),SUMIF(N602:N625,">"&0),SUMIF(N626:N649,">"&0),SUMIF(N650:N673,">"&0),SUMIF(N674:N697,">"&0),SUMIF(N698:N721,">"&0),SUMIF(N722:N745,">"&0),SUMIF(N746:N769,">"&0),SUMIF(N770:N793,">"&0),SUMIF(N794:N817,">"&0),SUMIF(N818:N841,">"&0),SUMIF(N842:N865,">"&0),SUMIF(N866:N889,">"&0),SUMIF(N890:N913,">"&0),SUMIF(N914:N937,">"&0),SUMIF(N938:N961,">"&0),SUMIF(N962:N985,">"&0),SUMIF(N986:N1009,">"&0),SUMIF(N1010:N1033,">"&0),SUMIF(N1034:N1057,">"&0),SUMIF(N1058:N1081,">"&0),SUMIF(N1082:N1105,">"&0),SUMIF(N1106:N1129,">"&0),SUMIF(N1130:N1153,">"&0),SUMIF(N1154:N1177,">"&0),SUMIF(N1178:N1201,">"&0),SUMIF(N1202:N1225,">"&0),SUMIF(N1226:N1249,">"&0),SUMIF(N1250:N1273,">"&0),SUMIF(N1274:N1297,">"&0),SUMIF(N1298:N1321,">"&0),SUMIF(N1322:N1345,">"&0),SUMIF(N1346:N1369,">"&0),SUMIF(N1370:N1393,">"&0),SUMIF(N1394:N1417,">"&0),SUMIF(N1418:N1441,">"&0),SUMIF(N1442:N1465,">"&0),SUMIF(N1466:N1489,">"&0),SUMIF(N1490:N1513,">"&0),SUMIF(N1514:N1537,">"&0),SUMIF(N1538:N1561,">"&0),SUMIF(N1562:N1585,">"&0),SUMIF(N1586:N1609,">"&0),SUMIF(N1610:N1633,">"&0),SUMIF(N1634:N1657,">"&0),SUMIF(N1658:N1681,">"&0),SUMIF(N1682:N1705,">"&0),SUMIF(N1706:N1729,">"&0),SUMIF(N1730:N1753,">"&0),SUMIF(N1754:N1777,">"&0),SUMIF(N1778:N1801,">"&0),SUMIF(N1802:N1825,">"&0),SUMIF(N1826:N1849,">"&0),SUMIF(N1850:N1873,">"&0),SUMIF(N1874:N1897,">"&0),SUMIF(N1898:N1921,">"&0),SUMIF(N1922:N1945,">"&0),SUMIF(N1946:N1969,">"&0),SUMIF(N1970:N1993,">"&0),SUMIF(N1994:N2017,">"&0),SUMIF(N2018:N2041,">"&0),SUMIF(N2042:N2065,">"&0),SUMIF(N2066:N2089,">"&0),SUMIF(N2090:N2113,">"&0),SUMIF(N2114:N2137,">"&0),SUMIF(N2138:N2161,">"&0),SUMIF(N2162:N2185,">"&0),SUMIF(N2186:N2209,">"&0),SUMIF(N2210:N2233,">"&0),SUMIF(N2234:N2257,">"&0),SUMIF(N2258:N2281,">"&0),SUMIF(N2282:N2305,">"&0),SUMIF(N2306:N2329,">"&0),SUMIF(N2330:N2353,">"&0),SUMIF(N2354:N2377,">"&0),SUMIF(N2378:N2401,">"&0),SUMIF(N2402:N2425,">"&0),SUMIF(N2426:N2449,">"&0),SUMIF(N2450:N2473,">"&0),SUMIF(N2474:N2497,">"&0),SUMIF(N2498:N2521,">"&0),SUMIF(N2522:N2545,">"&0),SUMIF(N2546:N2569,">"&0),SUMIF(N2570:N2593,">"&0),SUMIF(N2594:N2617,">"&0),SUMIF(N2618:N2641,">"&0),SUMIF(N2642:N2665,">"&0),SUMIF(N2666:N2689,">"&0),SUMIF(N2690:N2713,">"&0),SUMIF(N2714:N2737,">"&0),SUMIF(N2738:N2761,">"&0),SUMIF(N2762:N2785,">"&0),SUMIF(N2786:N2809,">"&0),SUMIF(N2810:N2833,">"&0),SUMIF(N2834:N2857,">"&0),SUMIF(N2858:N2881,">"&0),SUMIF(N2882:N2905,">"&0),SUMIF(N2906:N2929,">"&0),SUMIF(N2930:N2953,">"&0),SUMIF(N2954:N2977,">"&0),SUMIF(N2978:N3001,">"&0),SUMIF(N3002:N3025,">"&0),SUMIF(N3026:N3049,">"&0),SUMIF(N3050:N3073,">"&0),SUMIF(N3074:N3097,">"&0),SUMIF(N3098:N3121,">"&0),SUMIF(N3122:N3145,">"&0),SUMIF(N3146:N3169,">"&0),SUMIF(N3170:N3193,">"&0),SUMIF(N3194:N3217,">"&0),SUMIF(N3218:N3241,">"&0),SUMIF(N3242:N3265,">"&0),SUMIF(N3266:N3289,">"&0),SUMIF(N3290:N3313,">"&0),SUMIF(N3314:N3337,">"&0),SUMIF(N3338:N3361,">"&0),SUMIF(N3362:N3385,">"&0),SUMIF(N3386:N3409,">"&0),SUMIF(N3410:N3433,">"&0),SUMIF(N3434:N3457,">"&0),SUMIF(N3458:N3481,">"&0),SUMIF(N3482:N3505,">"&0),SUMIF(N3506:N3529,">"&0),SUMIF(N3530:N3553,">"&0),SUMIF(N3554:N3577,">"&0),SUMIF(N3578:N3601,">"&0),SUMIF(N3602:N3625,">"&0),SUMIF(N3626:N3649,">"&0),SUMIF(N3650:N3673,">"&0),SUMIF(N3674:N3697,">"&0),SUMIF(N3698:N3721,">"&0),SUMIF(N3722:N3745,">"&0),SUMIF(N3746:N3769,">"&0),SUMIF(N3770:N3793,">"&0),SUMIF(N3794:N3817,">"&0),SUMIF(N3818:N3841,">"&0),SUMIF(N3842:N3865,">"&0),SUMIF(N3866:N3889,">"&0),SUMIF(N3890:N3913,">"&0),SUMIF(N3914:N3937,">"&0),SUMIF(N3938:N3961,">"&0),SUMIF(N3962:N3985,">"&0),SUMIF(N3986:N4009,">"&0),SUMIF(N4010:N4033,">"&0),SUMIF(N4034:N4057,">"&0),SUMIF(N4058:N4081,">"&0),SUMIF(N4082:N4105,">"&0),SUMIF(N4106:N4129,">"&0),SUMIF(N4130:N4153,">"&0),SUMIF(N4154:N4177,">"&0),SUMIF(N4178:N4201,">"&0),SUMIF(N4202:N4225,">"&0),SUMIF(N4226:N4249,">"&0),SUMIF(N4250:N4273,">"&0),SUMIF(N4274:N4297,">"&0),SUMIF(N4298:N4321,">"&0),SUMIF(N4322:N4345,">"&0),SUMIF(N4346:N4369,">"&0),SUMIF(N4370:N4393,">"&0),SUMIF(N4394:N4417,">"&0),SUMIF(N4418:N4441,">"&0),SUMIF(N4442:N4465,">"&0),SUMIF(N4466:N4489,">"&0),SUMIF(N4490:N4513,">"&0),SUMIF(N4514:N4537,">"&0),SUMIF(N4538:N4561,">"&0),SUMIF(N4562:N4585,">"&0),SUMIF(N4586:N4609,">"&0),SUMIF(N4610:N4633,">"&0),SUMIF(N4634:N4657,">"&0),SUMIF(N4658:N4681,">"&0),SUMIF(N4682:N4705,">"&0),SUMIF(N4706:N4729,">"&0),SUMIF(N4730:N4753,">"&0),SUMIF(N4754:N4777,">"&0),SUMIF(N4778:N4801,">"&0),SUMIF(N4802:N4825,">"&0),SUMIF(N4826:N4849,">"&0),SUMIF(N4850:N4873,">"&0),SUMIF(N4874:N4897,">"&0),SUMIF(N4898:N4921,">"&0),SUMIF(N4922:N4945,">"&0),SUMIF(N4946:N4969,">"&0),SUMIF(N4970:N4993,">"&0),SUMIF(N4994:N5017,">"&0),SUMIF(N5018:N5041,">"&0),SUMIF(N5042:N5065,">"&0),SUMIF(N5066:N5089,">"&0),SUMIF(N5090:N5113,">"&0),SUMIF(N5114:N5137,">"&0),SUMIF(N5138:N5161,">"&0),SUMIF(N5162:N5185,">"&0),SUMIF(N5186:N5209,">"&0),SUMIF(N5210:N5233,">"&0),SUMIF(N5234:N5257,">"&0))`

And in a separate cell

`=MAX(SUMIF(N5258:N5281,">"&0),SUMIF(N5282:N5305,">"&0),SUMIF(N5306:N5329,">"&0),SUMIF(N5330:N5353,">"&0),SUMIF(N5354:N5377,">"&0),SUMIF(N5378:N5401,">"&0),SUMIF(N5402:N5425,">"&0),SUMIF(N5426:N5449,">"&0),SUMIF(N5450:N5473,">"&0),SUMIF(N5474:N5497,">"&0),SUMIF(N5498:N5521,">"&0),SUMIF(N5522:N5545,">"&0),SUMIF(N5546:N5569,">"&0),SUMIF(N5570:N5593,">"&0),SUMIF(N5594:N5617,">"&0),SUMIF(N5618:N5641,">"&0),SUMIF(N5642:N5665,">"&0),SUMIF(N5666:N5689,">"&0),SUMIF(N5690:N5713,">"&0),SUMIF(N5714:N5737,">"&0),SUMIF(N5738:N5761,">"&0),SUMIF(N5762:N5785,">"&0),SUMIF(N5786:N5809,">"&0),SUMIF(N5810:N5833,">"&0),SUMIF(N5834:N5857,">"&0),SUMIF(N5858:N5881,">"&0),SUMIF(N5882:N5905,">"&0),SUMIF(N5906:N5929,">"&0),SUMIF(N5930:N5953,">"&0),SUMIF(N5954:N5977,">"&0),SUMIF(N5978:N6001,">"&0),SUMIF(N6002:N6025,">"&0),SUMIF(N6026:N6049,">"&0),SUMIF(N6050:N6073,">"&0),SUMIF(N6074:N6097,">"&0),SUMIF(N6098:N6121,">"&0),SUMIF(N6122:N6145,">"&0),SUMIF(N6146:N6169,">"&0),SUMIF(N6170:N6193,">"&0),SUMIF(N6194:N6217,">"&0),SUMIF(N6218:N6241,">"&0),SUMIF(N6242:N6265,">"&0),SUMIF(N6266:N6289,">"&0),SUMIF(N6290:N6313,">"&0),SUMIF(N6314:N6337,">"&0),SUMIF(N6338:N6361,">"&0),SUMIF(N6362:N6385,">"&0),SUMIF(N6386:N6409,">"&0),SUMIF(N6410:N6433,">"&0),SUMIF(N6434:N6457,">"&0),SUMIF(N6458:N6481,">"&0),SUMIF(N6482:N6505,">"&0),SUMIF(N6506:N6529,">"&0),SUMIF(N6530:N6553,">"&0),SUMIF(N6554:N6577,">"&0),SUMIF(N6578:N6601,">"&0),SUMIF(N6602:N6625,">"&0),SUMIF(N6626:N6649,">"&0),SUMIF(N6650:N6673,">"&0),SUMIF(N6674:N6697,">"&0),SUMIF(N6698:N6721,">"&0),SUMIF(N6722:N6745,">"&0),SUMIF(N6746:N6769,">"&0),SUMIF(N6770:N6793,">"&0),SUMIF(N6794:N6817,">"&0),SUMIF(N6818:N6841,">"&0),SUMIF(N6842:N6865,">"&0),SUMIF(N6866:N6889,">"&0),SUMIF(N6890:N6913,">"&0),SUMIF(N6914:N6937,">"&0),SUMIF(N6938:N6961,">"&0),SUMIF(N6962:N6985,">"&0),SUMIF(N6986:N7009,">"&0),SUMIF(N7010:N7033,">"&0),SUMIF(N7034:N7057,">"&0),SUMIF(N7058:N7081,">"&0),SUMIF(N7082:N7105,">"&0),SUMIF(N7106:N7129,">"&0),SUMIF(N7130:N7153,">"&0),SUMIF(N7154:N7177,">"&0),SUMIF(N7178:N7201,">"&0),SUMIF(N7202:N7225,">"&0),SUMIF(N7226:N7249,">"&0),SUMIF(N7250:N7273,">"&0),SUMIF(N7274:N7297,">"&0),SUMIF(N7298:N7321,">"&0),SUMIF(N7322:N7345,">"&0),SUMIF(N7346:N7369,">"&0),SUMIF(N7370:N7393,">"&0),SUMIF(N7394:N7417,">"&0),SUMIF(N7418:N7441,">"&0),SUMIF(N7442:N7465,">"&0),SUMIF(N7466:N7489,">"&0),SUMIF(N7490:N7513,">"&0),SUMIF(N7514:N7537,">"&0),SUMIF(N7538:N7561,">"&0),SUMIF(N7562:N7585,">"&0),SUMIF(N7586:N7609,">"&0),SUMIF(N7610:N7633,">"&0),SUMIF(N7634:N7657,">"&0),SUMIF(N7658:N7681,">"&0),SUMIF(N7682:N7705,">"&0),SUMIF(N7706:N7729,">"&0),SUMIF(N7730:N7753,">"&0),SUMIF(N7754:N7777,">"&0),SUMIF(N7778:N7801,">"&0),SUMIF(N7802:N7825,">"&0),SUMIF(N7826:N7849,">"&0),SUMIF(N7850:N7873,">"&0),SUMIF(N7874:N7897,">"&0),SUMIF(N7898:N7921,">"&0),SUMIF(N7922:N7945,">"&0),SUMIF(N7946:N7969,">"&0),SUMIF(N7970:N7993,">"&0),SUMIF(N7994:N8017,">"&0),SUMIF(N8018:N8041,">"&0),SUMIF(N8042:N8065,">"&0),SUMIF(N8066:N8089,">"&0),SUMIF(N8090:N8113,">"&0),SUMIF(N8114:N8137,">"&0),SUMIF(N8138:N8161,">"&0),SUMIF(N8162:N8185,">"&0),SUMIF(N8186:N8209,">"&0),SUMIF(N8210:N8233,">"&0),SUMIF(N8234:N8257,">"&0),SUMIF(N8258:N8281,">"&0),SUMIF(N8282:N8305,">"&0),SUMIF(N8306:N8329,">"&0),SUMIF(N8330:N8353,">"&0),SUMIF(N8354:N8377,">"&0),SUMIF(N8378:N8401,">"&0),SUMIF(N8402:N8425,">"&0),SUMIF(N8426:N8449,">"&0),SUMIF(N8450:N8473,">"&0),SUMIF(N8474:N8497,">"&0),SUMIF(N8498:N8521,">"&0),SUMIF(N8522:N8545,">"&0),SUMIF(N8546:N8569,">"&0),SUMIF(N8570:N8593,">"&0),SUMIF(N8594:N8617,">"&0),SUMIF(N8618:N8641,">"&0),SUMIF(N8642:N8665,">"&0),SUMIF(N8666:N8689,">"&0),SUMIF(N8690:N8713,">"&0),SUMIF(N8714:N8737,">"&0),SUMIF(N8738:N8761,">"&0),SUMIF(N8762:N8785,">"&0))`

The Max() of these two cells is the total for the year. It's brute force but it solves the speed issue.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort but this is 'too much' .

Unless someone finds an elegant solution I must conclude that Excel still has limitations that makes it not possible to perform the required calculations elegant and fast even though it is easy to fumulate what should be calculated.